# Eager loading at Collection level with Annotation in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Uable to achieve aggressive/eager loading at Collection level.

I know eager loading at collection level with XML

[image]

**but How I could achieve the same with annotation at collection level.**?

**Student Persistence Class**

[image]

Here I need to do eager loading for Collection Type **semails** field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using hibernate you can use `@Fetch` annotation with FetchMode.JOIN. This will make hibernate use join and fetch collection with a single select query joining your element collection table.
Make sure your collection has two annotations:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
```

Comment: @llya Serebryannikov , not working. Still unable to get semails records as eager loading.

Comment: @Kms, can you demonstrate what queries does hibernate make?

Comment: @liya, was following wrong steps. Yes I'm able to get that one. Please find the SQL query generated by Hibernate system.  Hibernate: select student0_.sid as sid1_1_0_, student0_.sname as sname2_1_0_, semails1_.sid as sid1_0_1_, semails1_.emails as emails2_0_1_, semails1_.idx as idx3_1_ from StudentsTable student0_ left outer join Emails semails1_ on student0_.sid=semails1_.sid where student0_.sid=?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the fetch type in the annotation @ElementCollection:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
```